# How to perform a fulltext search in django array field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, models

I have an `ArrayField` of strings and I want to search if any of the items are containing any of the items within an intended set of strings.

I have defined the field like this:

```
class Path(models.Model):
    path = models.TextField()
    files = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300))
    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.path
```

And I want to check let's say if the files are containing any name that may contain one of these strings `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. That means if the `files` is containing the following items:

```
['example', 'examplebar']
```

I want it to return true.

I already looked into all the related methods for an ArrayField but none of them seems to work.

I want something that is a combination of `contains` and `overlap`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like django supports this directly, so you'll have to do it manually by going through the list and search for the substrings.

If you have a `Path` object in the variable `path`, and the strings you are searching for in `substrings`, you can do this:

```
for file in path.files:
    for s in substrings:
        if s in file:
            return True

return False
```

If you want it to be handled purely by the database you'll have to create a new table for the paths and use foreign keys, instead of `ArrayField`.